# extjs group by letter

Tags: extjs

does anyone knows how to use extjs's groupingview and group by the first letter of the particular field indicated by the groupingStore?

For instance:

```
group 'l':
record with field 'lion'
record with field 'leopard'

group 'g':
record with field 'giraffe'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok i got it. Basically I need to edit the grid column's groupRenderer :

```
groupRenderer:function(v,u,r,rowIndex,colIndex,js){
            return r.get('fieldname').charAt(0);
        },
```